# Getting InsufficientPrivileges when trying to send message in MS Teams channel via sendMessageInchannel API

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

Post Request :[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)

Response I am getting:

```
Response :
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "InsufficientPrivileges",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "1",
            "message": "AclCheckFailed-The initiator 8:orgid: is not a member
                        of the roster  in the generic thread",
            "date": "2024-02-07T07:37:19",
            "request-id": "",
            "client-request-id": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I tried checking whether I am having the read and write permission on teams channel where I am trying to send a message , even I tried making myself admin of that channel , Manually I am able to send messages on that channel but not through this API